# Lookup OSGI service which is registered with wildcard property

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I know that one can lookup service from the OSGI service registry using properties wildcards. This question is about doing it the other way round.

Basically you register a service like this:

```
Map<String, String. prop = new HashMap<String, String>();
prop.put("name", "europe-*"); // this is the point - the service is registered with property containing wildcard 
context.registerService(IService.class.getName(), new ContinentServiceEuropeImpl(), prop);
```

and then you would like to lookup this service with a concrete value for this property, like this:

```
ServiceTracker primaryTracker = new ServiceTracker(bundleContext, "(&(objectClass=<IService class name here>)(name=europe-spain))", null);
```

This won't find the service as the service registration property is not considered as wildcard i.e. you would find the service only if you ask specifically for `(name=europe-*)` - (not sure if you have to escape the * when you look up for * literal)

To contrast this - usually it is the other way round - you register a service with a concrete property value i.e. `(name=europe-spain)` and then you look it up by using `(name=europe-*)` - this works, but unfortunately it is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work that way. The properties in the service registration are values which can be searched over using a filter expression.

You can either do this:

```
ServiceTracker primaryTracker = new ServiceTracker(bundleContext, "(&(objectClass=<IService class name here>)(|(name=europe-spain)(name=europe-\\*))", null);
```

which will look for either europe-spain or europe-*. Or you can register the service with name values it supports:

```
prop.put("name", new String[]{"europe-spain","europe-france",...});
```

Comment: I need to support europe-*, europe-spain-* (for example for the regions), europe-*-*, etc., it is basically very dynamic. The thing is that the services I am trying to look for are not under my control i.e. they are going to be registered by "plugins" so they could use wildcard "*" and separator "-" however they see fit.  Your second suggestion ... the name values are dynamic and available only at runtime; Along the lines of this solution. I thought about registering a service per name value, but this would quickly go out of hand with a lot of values to support.

Comment: If there is no control over the property values, then you are lost. There needs to be some meaning to the property values if you want to do something with them. Obviously the bundle registering the service with the service property "name" is trying to communicate something to the potential users of the service. So there needs to be rules regarding the permissible values of the property. In effect, the property is a contract between the provider and consumer of the service and this contract must specify the rules for valid property values so that consumers can understand them.